# TableView for UISearchController under other components on view

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am using [UISearchBar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar) with [UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller) which is using a `UITableView` to display search results in a drop-down.

There are several components on a view (fields and buttons) and part of the table view is hidden under them.

How do I get the table view to show over other components in the view?

Comment: Isn't the `bringSubview(toFront: tableView)` method the what you're looking for? You can place your table view on top of all the other subviews and keep it `hidden` until the user tap on search view.

Comment: I will try that and report my findings. Thanks